# Update MATLAB GUI when a file is changed

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I created a GUI with GUIDE Matlab  that reads a file when the GUI starts and after read the data from the file the GUI behaves according the data.

These GUI should be a front end of a program that is every 5 miliseconds changing the file that the GUI reads. So what i'm trying to reach is a GUI that updates itself reading that file. The code that i have made for the starting of the GUI is below.

```
% --- Executes just before GUI is made visible.
function GUI_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
% This function has no output args, see OutputFcn.
% hObject    handle to figure
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
% varargin   command line arguments to GUI (see VARARGIN)

%DATA from file
[features_int,features_double,ascan]=read_file;
%Ascan display
handles.current_data=ascan(1:2500,1);
%Catarata Type
handles.catarata=features_int(6,1);
%Table Values
table_data=cell(4,2);
table_data(:,1)=[cellstr('');cellstr('Tempo de Voo');cellstr('Coeficiente de Kurtosis CrP');cellstr('Coeficiente de Kurtosis CrA')];
table_data(:,2)=[cellstr('Valor');num2cell(features_double(1,1));num2cell(features_double(19,1));num2cell(features_double(18,1))];
handles.features=table_data;
set(handles.table_feature,'ColumnWidth',{200,100});
set(handles.table_feature,'Data',handles.features);

%Plot Ascan
plot(handles.current_data)
box off;
hold on;
cra_x = [features_int(4,1)-1 features_int(4,1)-1 features_int(4,1)+1 features_int(4,1)+1];
cra_y = [-15000 15000 15000 -15000];
crp_x = [features_int(5,1)-1 features_int(5,1)-1 features_int(5,1)+1 features_int(5,1)+1];
crp_y = [-15000 15000 15000 -15000];
h=fill(cra_x,cra_y,'r',crp_x,crp_y,'m');
set(h,'facealpha',.7);
set(h,'EdgeColor','none');
legend(h,'Cristalino Anterior','Cristalino Posterior','Location','SOUTH');
legend boxoff;

%LED Config
if (features_int(6)==1)
    set(handles.catarata_type,'String','Catarata Tipo 1');
    set(handles.led,'Background','y');
elseif(features_int(6)==2)
    set(handles.catarata_type,'String','Catarata Tipo 2');
    set(handles.led,'Background',[1,0.6,0]);
elseif(features_int(6)==3)
    set(handles.catarata_type,'String','Catarata Tipo 3');
    set(handles.led,'Background','r');
else
    set(handles.catarata_type,'String','Sem Catarata');
    set(handles.led,'Background','g');
end


% Choose default command line output for GUI
handles.output = hObject;
% Update handles structure
guidata(hObject,handles);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: So your gui loads a file, display a table and a fill plot ... Past that I fail to understand a clear question. What are you asking exactly ?

Comment: Yes that is correct. The problem is that i'm changing the file every 5 miliseconds and i want to see that changes at the GUI. Because the plot and the table will change according to the data loaded.

Comment: @Jmaio23 So you want your GUI to change it's display every 5 ms ? I highly doubt you can load data and display them in less than 5 ms, or is it that you only add data that you concatenate to the previous data ?

Comment: in your `GUI_OpeningFcn`: just put the code to _initialize_ the table and plot (make them empty even if necessary). Then create a timer, and in the timer callback function: read file/process/display. It's unlikely that you'll achieve a true 5ms refresh rate (specially if you need disk access), you may consider averaging/collating and displaying only every so often (half second or one second is good enough for most displays...)

Comment: Every 5 ms i get 4096 new samples in my file. The problem is that the samples are not coming one on one, they are coming in chunks of 4096 every 5ms. But i can concatenate the data in file

Comment: So i should not plot anything in GUI_OPENINGFcn? Could you give me some hints about the creation of the timer?

Comment: @Jmaio23 so to clarify, do you want the GUI to read the file and update every 5 ms? If this is what you mean it may get tough to manage this within the time frame given. This is matlab after all and reading from the hard drive is normally a bit slow. Would you accept a longer time frame? let us say, a few times per second?

Comment: Yes @patrik, it could be a solution

Comment: And regarding where this is done, no not in the opening function. You should handle this with callback functions.

Comment: Yeah, i understood that i need to use a time callback function. The problem is that i'm not familiar with timers in Matlab. So i'm pretty confused on how i should do it.

Comment: There is a good example [here](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/timer-callback-functions.html).